# prettyPhoto changepicturecallback data

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

Anyone know how to retrieve the current image data (alt, src) via the changepicturecallback function with Jquery prettyPhoto?

I want to pass these two variables to an ajax script and can't seem to get my hands on the info to pass. Tried this to no avail.

```
    var image = jQuery(".pp_pic_holder").find("#pp_full_res img").attr("src");
```

There must be a way to easily access this data at run time.
Any suggestions or point in the right direction?

When I was working with Gallerific I was able to get this info using

```
var image_src = this.data[nextIndex].slideUrl;
```

EDIT => Just had to narrow my search down for the target

```
        var image = jQuery('#fullResImage').attr('src');
```

Works just fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, your attempt is right, but try to broaden your scope a bit, and do some testing...

```
myCallbackTest = function() {
  alert('the callback worked! thats a good start!');

  var $activeimage = $("#fullResImage");

  var source = $activeimage.attr('src'), altText = $activeimage.attr('alt');

  if(!$activeimage.length) {
    alert('The image selector failed');
  } else if (!source) {
    alert('The image selector worked, but I found no source');
  } else if (!altText) {
    alert('Found The image and its source, but it doesnt seem to have any alt text');
  } else {
    alert('i got it! alt: ' + altText + ' src: ' + source);
  } 
}
```

Then give it a go...

```
$(function() {
  $('a[rel^=prettyPhoto]').prettyPhoto({
    theme: 'facebook',
    slideshow:5000, 
    autoplay_slideshow:true,
    changepicturecallback: myCallbackTest
  });
});
```